# Finite loop crashing browser

Tags: javascript, for-loop, arguments

I am hoping someone can explain what is wrong with my for loop. If I type out the for loop as if(arguments[2]){ stable = rere(stable, arguments[2]);} it works as intended. I could have more than 6 arguments and would like to understand why this loop isn't functioning properly.

```
function sym() {
  function rere(a,b){
    var check = [];
    for(i=a.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      for(x=b.length-1; x>=0; x--){
        if(a[i] == b[x]){
          check.push( a.splice(i,1) );         
        }
      }
    }

    for(i=b.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      for(x=check.length-1; x>=0; x--){
        if(b[i] == check[x][0]){
          b.splice(i,1);
        }
      }
    }
    var stable = a.concat(b);
    return stable;
  }
  var stable = rere(arguments[0], arguments[1]);

//problem is HERE. The for loop repeating rere function crashes repl.it

  for(i=2; i<arguments.length; i++){
    stable = rere(stable, arguments[i]);
   }
//End problem.

  stable = stable.filter(function(a,b,c){
    return b == c.indexOf(a);
   });
  return stable;
}

sym([3, 3, 3, 2, 5], [2, 1, 5, 7], [3, 4, 6, 6], [1, 2, 3], [5, 3, 9, 8], [1]);
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: So you want to filter out duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You're reusing the `i` variable by not declaring it in `rere()`, so it gets reset on each iteration of the problem loop.

To fix it, properly declare `i` inside `rere()` using `let` or `var`.

Comment: If he declares it, it gets reset too. no?

Comment: More than that: It's pretty advisable to prepend a `"use strict";` row at top of the code to avoid common mistakes like this.

Comment: @techjs no, its all about scope.

Comment: @TechJS: No, the problem loop will be using an `i` distinct from the `rere` one.

Comment: @bitifet or you just declare variables... ( as a habit)

Comment: @bitifet: Good point, but I think it wouldn't be caught if it was declared in the outer function but not the inner `rere`. Would be nice if shadowing could be avoided altogether.

Comment: Why is that? It doesn't make sense to me that the interation for i needs to be declared inside the function. What is a good resource where I can read about this.

Comment: @Jonasw habits can fail. Strict mode forces you to do things right. There is no sane reason to not using it except for ancient code you know/hope works and don't want to review.

Comment: @DevinElder: After you call `rere` in the first iteration of the problem loop, what is the value of `i`? The `rere` function changed it, so it won't be where it left off before you made that call, so the `i<arguments.length` won't give the expected result.

Comment: @devin *always declare variables!* -> just a tip from everybody coding in js for a longer time.

Comment: You're right @spanky. But many times functions are written and tested before its final use so there is a chance to detect the problem before it actually happen (when defining the variable in the outer scope).

Comment: @DevinElder: "Scope and Closures" title of "You don't know js" series (you asked for a good resource, not for a brief onw ;-)) Link: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

Comment: Kyle Simpson is a genius, loved the books.